# I am making a custom unity tool

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a custom unity tool and which uses data from a scriptable object. How do I edit data on that scriptable object. I mean I how do I take reference of that scriptable object in editor script.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can find your asset via `AssetDatabase.FindAssets($"t:{typeof(YOUR TYPE)}");` .. but if there is supposedly only one anyway you should rather add it as a part of the player settings -> [`SettingsProvider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SettingsProvider.html)

Comment: You see, I Made a scriptable object which has information of obstacles as 2d matrix.
Now I am trying to make editor tool which will edit that data of scriptable object. Then I will read that scriptable object and generate obstacles and save data. I hope you understand. I am making tool for first time.

Comment: Why use a scriptable object at all though? Sounds like a simple JSON file could do the same

Comment: that is kind of assignment

Comment: In that case please refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ... your question in its current state is to vague to provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple Editor for your class so the button "Import" would show up in inspector and if you click it you can know which object was selected (Editor.target)

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScriptableObject))]
MyScriptableObjectEditor : Editor{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        if(GUILayout.Button("Import"))
        {
            DoYourStuff(target as MyScriptableObject);
        }
    }      
}

void DoYourStuff(MyScriptableObject targetObject){
     //Do your stuff here
}
```